# Vim: Can you delete a specific line number from another line?

Tags: vim

I was on line 93 and realized I wanted to delete line 89.
I typed `:d89` in hopes that line 89 wold be deleted.
It didn't work.

Does anyone know a good way to accomplish this type of interaction?
I am a comfortable Vim user but have not (yet) taken the leap to writing plugins...

Thanks.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The address of a colon-command (eg: the line number) comes first.

```
:89d
```

Note that this will also cause you to navigate to the location of the change. You can use ``` `` ``` to jump back.

If you'd prefer to have this be a single command you can define a custom command. eg:

```
command! -range -nargs=0 Delete <line1>,<line2>d|norm ``
```

This defines a command called `Delete` that deletes the addressed range (`<line1>,<line2>d`) and then navigates back (``` norm `` ```).

You can call it like:

```
:89Delete
```

You can actually invoke it with any unique prefix, so you may be able to get it down to:

```
:89D
```

Comment: hum... why not simply try the suggestion and see what happens?

Comment: +1, well the command here consists of the "address" (which may be a line number) and the command.

Comment: @Ethan The behavior is similar to navigating to 89 and then deleting it. This is pretty common behavior for colon-commands. `:s` leaves you on the line of the last substitution, for example.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the fix. Any modifications that can skip/reduce the '' requirement?

Comment: @Ethan `''` is a little easier to type, but it doesn't preserve the column position. You could also define a custom command if you wanted to. See update to answer.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Awesome. Vim laziness upgraded to new heights.

Answer (score 20):

`:89d` will delete the 89th line.

`:89,91d` will delete the 89th 90th and 91st line.

These functions also work in the [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) plugin for [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/), and the Vim Extension for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Answer (score 1):

What you're searching for is probably

```
:89d|'`
```

The `|` chains commands together.