# Delete specific line in vim directly from command mode

Tags: vim

If I'm in command mode in vim, can I remove a specific line without first going there?

Say I want to remove line 10, I could do:

```
:10
dd
```

But those are two commands. Can I do this in one command?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495094/vim-can-you-delete-a-specific-line-number-from-another-line.  It doesn't seem it's possible without actually going there, but at least deleting and doing there are combined into one command

Comment: `:h deleting` shows you many ways to delete, including the direct answer to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to do `:<number>d`. For example `:10d` should delete the 10th line.

To get back to where you started you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

From [Vim: Can you delete a specific line number from another line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495094/vim-can-you-delete-a-specific-line-number-from-another-line):

The answer would be yes, by doing the following:

`:10d`

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be this :

```
:10|:normal dd
```

Let's decompose that :

- `|` let you chain commands
- `:10` is the command to go to the 10th line
- `:normal dd` let you emulate keystrokes in normal mode (in your case just `dd`, but you could have used `:normal jdd` to go down and then delete)

Source :
[Learn Vim Scripting The Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/28.html)