# How will I delete particular line no in vi Editor?

Tags: linux, shell, vi

EX :  if there are 10000 line in a text file ,I need to delete only line no 777.

Comment: `777gg` to goto line `777` then `dd` to delete.

Answer (score 0):

try :[lineno.]d

Example:

If you want to delete line number 50

use command :50d

source [Vim: Can you delete a specific line number from another line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495094/vim-can-you-delete-a-specific-line-number-from-another-line)