# Vim: Jump to line and change from another line?

Tags: vim

I know from the question ["Vim: Can you delete a specific line number from another line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495094/vim-can-you-delete-a-specific-line-number-from-another-line) that you delete a specific line by using `:95d`.

As far as I understand Vim, then it should be possible to use verbs in any combination, e.g. where you can use `d` (delete), you should also be able to use `c` (change) or `y` (yank). This does not seem to be the case with the jump-to-line motion. If I do a `:95c` then I would expect it to go to line 95 and change that line. This does not happen. Vim just stares at me, waiting for my next input.

I am aware i could just `:95` and then `cc`, but since Vim is all about productivity and as few keystrokes as possible, I was hoping for a command similar to `:95d`

Is there any way to jump to a specific line and change it, in one command and without macros/binds (I'm trying to keep my install as clean as possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If you go through command-line mode, you'll have to live with the peculiarities of the used Ex command.*

For delete, there's not much difference between `:95d<CR>` and `95Gdd` (both five keys, one of them shifted). For change, the `:change` command does not go into interactive editing, as you expect, but instead asks for the replacement text on the command-line (concluded by entering a single `.` on a separate line), as [`:help :change`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Achange) explains.

If that's weird for you, then by all means use `95Gcc`, or `:95norm! cc<CR>` if you insist on going through command-line mode.

Comment: Agreed, use `95G` instead of `:95`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - Thanks for your answer!